# How to scale vertices uniformly in one direction?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I want to scale a set of vertices off the center and towards a point.

Here's the current setup :

[image]

I want to scale the selected vertices equally towards the edge of the wing. Scaling in X axis isn't working.

What's the correct method here ?

Answer (score 1):

### Pivot is the origin, not the goal.

The pivot point is considered the **origin** of the transformation space. Scaling the objects with a factor smaller than 1 will make them collapse toward the origin, while what you would like to achieve is verteices spreaded **from** the origin toward another point. The scaling factor should be greater than 1 in this case (e.g. the double, the triple...).

I suggest to change the position of the 3D cursor to the symmetry axis instead of the goal point. This way you'll be able to scale your vertices uniformly, even if they are not evenly spaced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do that, first steps :

- 1 : set pivot to median point for now
- 2 : enable proportional editing
- 3 : set it to linear

[image]

- Now hit <kbd>S</kbd> but dont validate it
- This is just a way to tune the proportional editing so that it bounds the points you want to scale
- Use the mouse wheel or <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> or plus the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to tune it more precisely
- Once done, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> as we don't want to move anything for now

[image]

- Set the pivot point to 3D cursor (indicated by 1 below)
- And hit <kbd>Scale</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

But to tell the truth, I am not sure this is the result you want. You may have to try with several proportional editing modes (sharp, root, sphere, smooth...) to see what is the best for you.

If needed, you may also hide the vertices you don't want to move so that the proportional size can be tuned without affecting the unwanted vertices (to hide select them and <kbd>H</kbd> ; to unhide <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LoopTools Addon for this task.

1) snap the last vertex of your plane to the desired destination location:

[image: snap last]

2) select the loop which you plan to space out evenly

[image: select loop]

3) click the 'space' function of the LoopTools Addon

[image: space evenly]